# how to capture jmeter log information

Tags: jmeter, robotframework, jmeter-3.2

In my jmeter script i am printing some information using `log.info` and same can be viewed via logviewer panel while executing scipt using jmeter tool but while running jmeter scipt via terminal how to capture the same?
NOTE: i am executing jmeter script via robotframework using keyword `Run Jmeter`

Is it possible to save the logviewer panel data in some file while executing script via terminal??

[image]

Answer (score 1):

JMeter writes its log to *jmeter.log* file, by default it's located in the "bin" folder of your JMeter installation. If you're running JMeter from other folder or using a desktop shortcut - the log file will be created in this location (assuming you have write access to this location)

If for some reason you need to override the location for the *jmeter.log* file - you can do it in 2 ways:

1. Provide the desired log file location via [`-j` command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) like:

   ```
   jmeter -j /somefolder/someotherfolder/my-jmeter.log -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
   ```
2. If you want to make the change permanent - locate this line in *log4j2.xml* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   <File name="jmeter-log" fileName="${sys:jmeter.logfile:-jmeter.log}" append="false">
   ```

   and change `filename` parameter to whatever you want.

More information:

- [JMeter Logging and error messages](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)
- [How to Configure JMeter Logging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging)

Comment: unfortunately while executing jmeter script from robotframework logs are not getting captured in jmeter.log file